# [Meta]What part of the world are you from?

Tags: meta

The chiphacker community has grown to a appreciable size. It would be nice to know what parts of the world we all come from.

I am from Ahmedabad,Gujarat,India.

Where do you come from.

**EDIT: *Country Summary***

```
USA             x 9
Australia       x 5
Canada          x 3
UK              x 3
India           x 4
Brazil          x 3
Romania         x 1
Denmark         x 1
The Netherlands x 1
Italy           x 1
France          x 1
Belgium         x 1
```

Comment: Can someone please update the country summary, little busy right now.

Comment: This thread is a hold-over from the previous SE 1.0 site, Chip Hacker. We don't really do this type of thing here. This site is focused on the information about Electronics and Robotics; the questions and answers but *not* really discussions about the users. Meta is to discuss the operation of the site. You are free to talk about "what part of the world are you from" in your profile by clicking on your name at the top of the site.

Answer (score 3):

The Netherlands!

Answer (score 1):

Namaste / As-Salamu Alaykum!

I'm from Tynemouth in Tyne and Wear (Near Newcastle), United Kingdom (England)

Comment: That would be Newcastle-upon-Tyne in the north-east of England where they used to dig coal and brew dark brown beer, as opposed to Newcastle-under-Lyme in Staffordshire where they, errr, used to dig coal and brew dark brown beer. ;)

Comment: Yup...but *shock horror* Newcastle Brown Ale is now made in Sunderland! - What a cop out!

Answer (score 1):

Toowong, Brisbane, Australia. 
However I'm moving to a place just outside Cessnock, NSW at the end of the year. 
[edit] 01/01/2011. Now living between Maitland and Cessnock, NSW, Australia.

Comment: +1 for a cool place name :)

Comment: In the food court at the local shopping centre, there is one of those generic Asian food outlets called "Two Wongs"...

Answer (score 1):

Waterloo, Ontario, Canada here.

Answer (score 1):

Suffolk, England

Answer (score 1):

Grand Rapids, Michigan, United States of America.

Answer (score 1):

Cleveland, OH, USA.

Answer (score 1):

I am from Rome, Italy.

Comment: Never been more south then Firenze, but I am wearing my Italia Shirt today, that counts, right? Been three years since I was in Italia, and I miss it.

Answer (score 1):

India, West Bengal, Calcutta

Answer (score 1):

Sparta, New Jersey USA

Answer (score 1):

Perth WA Australia

Comment: Hey Rob - I used to work on a farm just up the road from you in Gingin, it's a small world dude!

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Santa Rita do Sapucaí, Minas Gerais, Brazil.

Answer (score 1):

Boston, Massachusetts, USA

(* jcl *)

Answer (score 1):

Stillwater, OK, USA.

Comment: Was that a question?? I suppose that it is Ok that you are from Stillwater. :-)

Comment: <3  I only live here temporarily. I hate living in the buffer zone between Kansas and Texas.

Comment: Have you discovered GeeksOK, the Geek Strike Force
http://www.geeksok.com/
?

Comment: I feel informed.

Answer (score 1):

Gilbert, AZ (near Phoenix) USA

Answer (score 1):

Aalborg, Denmark.

Answer (score 1):

Cardston, Alberta, Canada.

Answer (score 1):

Maroubra, Sydney, Australia

Answer (score 1):

Maroubra, Sydney, Australia

Answer (score 1):

Kennedale,  Texas

Comment: I just visited a friend in "The Colony"

Comment: Yup,  right up the highway.

Answer (score 1):

Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania, USA

Answer (score 1):

Bucharest, Romania

Answer (score 1):

I live in Bolton in the UK, but originally I'm from the Black Country (which is also in the UK).

Answer (score 1):

Skåne - Sweden - Europe

Answer (score 1):

San Diego, CA for the last 10 years, but originally from Sao Paulo, Brazil

Answer (score 1):

Tulsa, OK, USA. Considering moving elsewhere. I visit Wichita, KS, OK pretty often.

Comment: I visit OKC more often, but I like Tulsa.

Answer (score 1):

American expat in Montreal, QC, Canada.

Answer (score 1):

New Mexico (but originally from North Dakota), United States of America.

Nice to meet ya'll (yea I just said that)

Comment: I reckon I should holler: Howdy, neighbor!

Answer (score 1):

Boston, Massachusetts, USA

Answer (score 1):

Bangkok Thailand (www.logicthai.net)

Answer (score 1):

Grenoble, France, Europe

Comment: was a citizen of France till I turned 18...

Answer (score 1):

Sao Paulo - SP - Brazil.

Comment: He's my friend!

Answer (score 1):

Serbia
http://www.encodeteam.com/resume.html

Comment: rocks my resume

Answer (score 1):

Belgium, Oost-Vlaanderen

Answer (score 1):

Gurgaon, Haryana, India

Answer (score 1):

Ottawa, Ontario, Canada.

Answer (score 1):

Pune, Maharashtra, India.

Answer (score 1):

San Diego, California

Answer (score 1):

Sao Paulo - SP - Brazil.

Answer (score -1):

Moscow, Russia.

Answer (score -1):

Scaggsville, Maryland, USA

Answer (score -1):

Sydney, Australia

Answer (score -1):

I am from the United Kingdom.